# Starting a function on a firestore update

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The question is as easy as the title sugests.

To explain a little bit more, i'm a starter in android programming and I need my app to run a certain function everytime my firestore is updated.

```
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mDocRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                Map<String,Object> SMSFlag = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                String quotenum = documentSnapshot.getString(NUM_KEY);
                String quotemsg = documentSnapshot.getString(SMS_KEY);

                state = documentSnapshot.getString(STATE_KEY);
                if (state.equals("tosend")) {
                    try {
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(quotenum, null, quotemsg, null, null);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error sending SMS: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    SMSFlag.put(STATE_KEY, "sent");
                    mDocRef.set(SMSFlag);
                    state = documentSnapshot.getString(STATE_KEY);
                }
        }
    });
}
```

This is supposed to send a message. As you can see in the code I use a state key, this is because it was sending 3 sometimes 4 identical messages. After implementing the state it is sending only one (as its expected to) and sometimes two.

I want to know if theres a android method that I can replace onStart() for, because I think the problem is the method itself.

I hope I have explained myself well.
Thank you in advance for anyone willing to help

Comment: is there any reason you've put your code inside onStart?

Comment: I need the app to be working at all times, not just when a button is pressed. I did this using some yt vids and one of them used onStart so I went with it. idk if its recommended, I barely know android methods :/

Comment: I hope this answer helps you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By what you've mentioned I'd recomend you to put your code inside the `onCreate` lifecycle callback method:

```
protected void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    mDocRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                Map<String,Object> SMSFlag = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                String quotenum = documentSnapshot.getString(NUM_KEY);
                String quotemsg = documentSnapshot.getString(SMS_KEY);

                state = documentSnapshot.getString(STATE_KEY);
                if (state.equals("tosend")) {
                    try {
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(quotenum, null, quotemsg, null, null);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error sending SMS: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    SMSFlag.put(STATE_KEY, "sent");
                    mDocRef.set(SMSFlag);
                    state = documentSnapshot.getString(STATE_KEY);
                }
        }
    });
}
```

If you check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) on lifecycles you'll see that onStart might get called multiple times during the lifespan of your activity, which will attach multiple listeners to the `mDocRef` reference. That might be the cause why you were receiving multiple calls to it.

Comment: this appears to solve the problem! Thank you a lot. one last question. do you think this will be consuming to much energy? because I think this app is contantly checking the firestore for new values and i'm afraid this will be draining to much power?

Comment: Firebase listeners are "simply" websockets, if there is no activity they'll lose connection and return when something (your activity goes back to foreground, you receive an update) happens. I wouldn't worry about that, but you can manually disconnect the listeners if you want to. You can detach the listeners inside the callback method onStop https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener